# find common patterns btween two files

Tags: grep

i have two files, file1 have a column with ~600 row and file2 have ~20 columns and ~3000 row. 
i want to find patterns form file1 that are common in file2.

file1:

```
K00001
K00002
K00003
K00006
K00013
K00025
K00089
```

file2:

```
TRINITY_DN102283_c0_g1  KEGG:xtr:496432`KO:K16860
TRINITY_DN42420_c0_g1   KO:K01762
TRINITY_DN52581_c0_g1   KEGG:zma:732844`KO:K13523
TRINITY_DN36387_c0_g2   KEGG:zma:732811`KO:K00089
TRINITY_DN54650_c4_g1   KEGG:zma:542598`KO:K00025
TRINITY_DN93494_c0_g1   KEGG:zma:542598`KO:K00025
TRINITY_DN36051_c0_g1   KEGG:zma:542598`KO:K00025
```

i would like obtain a result like this:

```
K00025
K00089
```

Comment: yes i want ti find common words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the following snippet

```
grep -f file1 -o file2 | sort -u
K00025
K00089
```

Comment: thanks it is useful but few slow

Answer (score 2):

```
comm -12 <(grep -oP '\w+' a|sort -u) <(grep -oP '\w+' b|sort -u)
```

where:

- `grep -oP '\w+' a|sort -u` gets a sorted list o words in file `a`
- the some for file `b`
- `comm -12` outputs common lines