# How to compare the same word between multiple files?

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep, diff

I would like to count the same words across multiple files then show in which file they are.

**File1:**

```
This is so beautiful
```

**File2:**

```
There are so beautiful
```

**File3:**

```
so beautiful
```

The desired output 1:

```
so:3
beautiful:3
```

The desired output 2:

```
so:
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1

beautiful:
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1
```

Comment: This is a programming question and off-topic here.

Comment: but this is Linux instruction

Comment: Hi and Welcome to U&L! Please see the [help/on-topic] to see what this site is about.

Comment: I think I should go stackflow to ask this question?
sorry I think  I go wrong way

Comment: I have found many articles.
I found a similar question
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281307/find-common-patterns-btween-two-files
but it still not work for me

Comment: Does `file1:1` represent the count of the specific word in this file, or does it represent the line number where it was found?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```bsh
# Declare the files you want to include
files=( file* )

# Function to find common words in any number of files
wcomm() {
    # If no files provided, exit the function.
    [ $# -lt 1 ] && return 1
    # Extract words from first file
    local common_words=$(grep -o "\w*" "$1" | sort -u)
    while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
        # shift $1 to next file
        shift
        # Extract words from next file
        local next_words=$(grep -o "\w*" "$1" | sort -u)
        # Get only words in common from $common_words and $next_words
        common_words=$(comm -12 <(echo "${common_words,,}") <(echo "${next_words,,}"))
    done
    # Output the words common to all input files
    echo "$common_words"
}

# Output number of matches for each of the common words in total and per file
for w in $(wcomm "${files[@]}"); do
    echo $w:$(grep -oiw "$w" "${files[@]}" | wc -l);
    for f in "${files[@]}"; do
        echo $f:$(grep -oiw "$w" "$f" | wc -l);
    done;
    echo;
done
```

Output:

```
beautiful:3
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1

so:3
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1
```

**Explanation**:

Included as comments inside the script.

**Features**:

- As many files as your [ARG_MAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit) allows
- Finds all words separated by anything `grep` understands as word separator.
- Ignores case, so "beautiful" and "Beautiful" is the same word.

Comment: Thats intended. Common words are words that are shared in all files. That's what I understood from the question.

Answer (score 0):

This process displays the numbers of occurrences of words included in text files located in a directory or subdirectories, for each file and in all files.

1. Concatenate all text files.
2. Suppress duplicated words.

The result is a list of words and each word in the list is then counted in each file successively as well as in concatenated files.

3. Search the number of occurrences for each word in the list.

#### 1. Concatenate all text files

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

`find` searches all text files in the current directory or subdirectories and invoke `cat` to concatenate all matching files.

#### 2. Suppress duplicated words

Words may be placed separately on each line to create a list of words: each character other than a letter is replaced by a newline, then, a sequence of newlines is replaced by one newline.

```
tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]'
```

Finally, the duplicated words must be suppressed to get a suitable list of words. `uniq` may filter out repeated lines of text but the lines must be sorted, therefore, `sort` may be used to sort lines of text.

```
sort | uniq
```

or

```
sort -u
```

**Note:** a case-insensitive search may be performed adding the following command in the pipeline.

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

#### Potential issues

An existing script file should not be concatenated with other files even if it is located in the current directory or in subdirectories (c.f. `man find`).

```
find . -type f \( \! -name "*${0##*/}" \) -exec cat {} \;
```

**Note:** `$0` expands to the name of the shell. `${PARAMETER##WORD}` expands to the parameter with the longest matching pattern deleted (c.f. shell parameter expansions).

For example, `/usr/local/bin/myscript` becomes `myscript`.

#### Result

```
list=$(find . -type f \( \! -name "*${0##*/}" \) -exec cat {} \; | 
           tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u)
```

The command substitution allow to save the output of the *pipeline* in a variable.

#### 3. Search the number of occurrences...

**a) Searches all lines containing the given word, each occurrence on a different line...**

```
grep --exclude="*${0##*/}" -Rowi $word .
```

**... and counts number of lines**

```
grep --exclude="*${0##*/}" -Rowi $word . | wc -l
```

**b) Counts the matching lines for each input file.**

```
grep --exclude="*${0##*/}" -Rowi $word . | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |
    uniq -c | sed -E "$sed_script"
```

Searches all lines containing the given word (each occcurrence is on a different line), prints the number of occurrences as well as the source file and reformats data.

**Note:** `$0` expands to the name of the shell. `${PARAMETER##WORD}` expands to the parameter with the longest matching pattern deleted (c.f. shell parameter expansions).

For example, `/usr/local/bin/myscript` becomes `myscript`.

**Note:** `--exclude` is a GNU extension, **not** specified for **POSIX grep**. If this is an issue, then, remove the option and add the following statement at the top of the shell script.

```
# assign first positional parameter to "dirname"
# and move to this directory

dirname=${1:?first positional parameter missing\!}
cd "$dirname"
```

### Shell script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

list=$(find . -type f \( \! -name "*${0##*/}" \) -exec cat {} \; | 
           tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u)

# extract data and print formatted data
sed_script='s/([[:digit:]]+) (.*):[[:alpha:]]+/\2:\1/;s/[[:blank:]]+//'

for word in $list; do
    echo $word:$(grep --exclude="*${0##*/}" -Rowi $word . | wc -l)
    grep --exclude="*${0##*/}" -Rowi $word . | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | 
        uniq -c | sed -E "$sed_script"
    echo
done | sed -e "/^[[:alpha:]]\+:1/{N;N;d;}"
```

#### Input

```
prompt% cat file1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. cat cat
prompt% cat file2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. cat ut
prompt% cat file3
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed tristique egestas massa sed facilisis. Duis hendrerit ut. cat
tristique tristique tristique tristique
```

#### Output

```
adipiscing:2
./file2:1
./file3:1

amet:3
./file1:1
./file2:1
./file3:1

cat:4
./file1:2
./file2:1
./file3:1

consectetur:2
./file2:1
./file3:1

dolor:3
./file1:1
./file2:1
./file3:1

elit:2
./file2:1
./file3:1

ipsum:3
./file1:1
./file2:1
./file3:1

lorem:3
./file1:1
./file2:1
./file3:1

sed:2
./file3:2

sit:3
./file1:1
./file2:1
./file3:1

tristique:5
./file3:5

ut:2
./file2:1
./file3:1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!!
it helps, but actually I'm looking forward to compare two different article
and find the same word then print

Comment: he wants to search common words. so and beautiful are just examples.

Comment: Thank you !!
But I try this code I didn't got the same output like you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. if needed make adjustments

```
bash-4.1$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/output.txt

awk '{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
        Arr[$i]++
}
}
END{
for (i in Arr){
        if(Arr[i]>1)
        {
                print i":"Arr[i]
        }
}
}' file* > ${OUTPUT_FILE}

cat ${OUTPUT_FILE}
echo ""

IFS=":"
while read WORD TOTAL_COUNT
do
        echo "${WORD}:"
        for FILE_NAME in file*
        do
                COUNT=$(tr ' ' '\n' < ${FILE_NAME} | grep -c "${WORD}")
                if [ "${COUNT}" -gt "0" ]
                then
                        echo "${FILE_NAME}:${COUNT}"
                fi
        done
done < ${OUTPUT_FILE}


bash-4.1$ bash test.sh
beautiful:3
so:3

beautiful:
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1
so:
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1
```

Comment: you should explain your code. Letting code without comment like that could made people unsafe about using it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` to feed the words and files' name and then `awk` to reformat the output to get desired result:

```
grep -Ho '\w\+' file* |
awk -F':' '{ words[$1 FS $2]++; seen[$2]++ }
END{ for (x in seen) {
         print x":" seen[x];
         for (y in words) {
            if (y ~ "\\<" x "\\>")print substr(y, 1, length(y)-length(x)), words[y]
         }
     }
}'
```

This will give you a nice output as following (both desired outputs in one go):

```
so:3
file1: 1
file2: 1
file3: 1
This:1
file1: 1
beautiful:3
file3: 1
file1: 1
file2: 1
There:1
file2: 1
are:1
file2: 1
is:1
file1: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this all `awk` approach:

```
awk '
        {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {WC[$i]++
                                 FC[$i,FILENAME]++
                                }
        }
END     {for (w in WC) if (WC[w] > 1) print w, WC[w]

         print ""

         for (f in FC)  {split (f, T, SUBSEP)
                         w = T[1]
                         if (WC[w] > 1) {if (!D[w]) print w, ""
                                         print T[2], FC[f]
                                         D[w] = 1
                                        }
                        }
        }

' OFS=":" file[1-3]
so:3
beautiful:3

beautiful:
file3:1
file2:1
file1:1
so:
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1
```

It collects the respective data (word count & word count per file) for each file, and then, in the END section, produces the desired outputs 1 and 2, based on word count > 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write a code, just using fast way to know the results, you can use this command:

```
cat list_of_words | while read line; do echo $line; grep -riE '$line'-c where_to_look_or_folder; done

-r :read into files
-i: no casesensitive
-E: regexp is useable if you want something more complicated to search
-c: counter
```

Output:

```
word1
path:filename:count
```

Example:

```
cat text | while read line; do echo $line; grep -riE '$line'-c somwhwere/nowhere; done
```

Answer (score 0):

perl, counts all the words in the specified files, and for words seen more than once, print the total count and the count per file

```
$ cat file1
This is so beautiful
foo
foo
foo
$ cat file2
There are so beautiful
foo
bar
bar
$ cat file3
so beautiful
bar
baz
```

then

```
perl -lane '
    for (@F) {$count{$_}++; $filecount{$_}{$ARGV}++}
    END {
        for $word (sort keys %count) {
            if ($count{$word} > 1) {
                print "$word:$count{$word}";
                print "$_:$filecount{$word}{$_}" for sort keys %{ $filecount{$word} };
                print "";
            }
        }
    }
' file{1,2,3}
```

```
bar:3
file2:2
file3:1

beautiful:3
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1

foo:4
file1:3
file2:1

so:3
file1:1
file2:1
file3:1
```

To sort the results by descending order of "count", you would use this line in the END block:

```
for $word (reverse sort {$count{$a} <=> $count{$b}} keys %count) {
```

Comment: This work for me!!! Thank you so much! Can the output be from large amount to little?

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of language is this ? Thank you

Comment: What *kind* of language? I don't understand what you mean. You can learn more about perl on the [tag:perl] tag page.